# why doen't conflict diffs load on Filemerge, when other diffs do?

Tags: git, conflict, git-diff, filemerge

I have GIT set up to load Diffs in filemerge, but when there are conflicts, it just prints the diff to terminal.

Is there a way around this, or a better app to handle conflicts?

Comment: What are you exactly doing? Are you using 'git mergetool'?

Comment: I'm just using `git diff`, which is what I usually use to launch Filemerge to see diffs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, look into 'git mergetool' to configure a graphical editor to be able to handle the conflicts.